# Can I recoat my floor's matte finish with a satin sheen product?

Tags: flooring, hardwood, hardwood-refinishing, wood-finishing, wood-finish

I had my floors refinished in a water based Matte sheen.  They have no life.  Can I add a coat of satin to at least give them a little shine?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm guessing this completely depends on the finish product(s) involved; you should talk to the manufacturer (or installer). And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I add a coat of satin...?

**YES**

You will need to lightly sand the surface and thoroughly clean it, then add one or more additional coats of a compatible product that has the level of gloss you prefer.